# In Windows Vista Home Premium can an admin lock the machine so that no one one can "Switch User"?

Tags: windows-vista, administrator

Logged into an admin account, I am running a virus scan.

When I lock the machine, it allows other users to "Switch User" and log in. Is there a way I can temporarily prevent other users from loggin in?

Answer (score 1):

If you turn off fast user switching you can do this, but that requires a bit of registry editing in Vista.  You used to be able in XP to disable it via the control panel but no longer in Vista.  [Check this thread](http://forums.techarena.in/vista-administration/553823.htm)

Once that's done, you can Lock the computer and not have the switch user screen come up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Vista in front of me, but I believe if you check Services, there is a service named "Fast User Switching" . .  Disable and stop this service and you should be good.